# How can I prevent ClickOnce deployment with VS 2010 Excel Add-In

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, clickonce, excel-addins

In the past I have developed Excel Add-Ins using VS 2010.  These have all worked fine, but to get them installed I have had to create my own installation packages.  No problem.

I now have a new PC with VS 2010 installed.  So whenever I create a new Add-In the installation seems to automatically be handled by clickonce.  I.e. when launching the Add-In via debug, it seems to install the tool using clickonce.

This would be fine normally, but the project I am working has multiple components that I want to be installed in a single process (which doesn't seem to work with clickonce).

My question is, does anyone know how to disable the clickonce stuff?  And why are Add-Ins created using the new installation of VS different from my old one (I didn't install either)?  I'm doing *exactly* the same thing when creating them, but they behave differently.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually - I've found a workaround.  I've still no idea why the 2 setups are different though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just decided to live with the ClickOnce stuff and built a separate installation package for the remainder of the projects.